# Keycloak MySQL setup failed with error "Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back."

Tags: jpa, jboss, keycloak, liquibase

I tried with 8.x and 10.x version of Keycloak, also with tried with Keycloak docker image but getting below issue, while configuring Keycloak with MySQL

```
12:27:16,047 DEBUG [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Foreign key constraint added to USER_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP (USER_ID)
12:27:17,356 DEBUG [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Primary key added to GROUP_ROLE_MAPPING (ROLE_ID, GROUP_ID)
12:27:18,637 DEBUG [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Foreign key constraint added to GROUP_ROLE_MAPPING (GROUP_ID)
12:27:19,384 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
12:27:20,326 DEBUG [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Foreign key constraint added to GROUP_ROLE_MAPPING (ROLE_ID)
12:27:21,381 DEBUG [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Unique constraint added to REALM_DEFAULT_GROUPS(GROUP_ID)
12:27:23,153 DEBUG [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Foreign key constraint added to REALM_DEFAULT_GROUPS (REALM_ID)
12:27:24,389 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@2b5e08f5 for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:523)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1518)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1472)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1445)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$400(AbstractOperationContext.java:1319)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeResultHandlerPhase(AbstractOperationContext.java:876)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:726)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:527)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
        at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:448)
        at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:401)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

12:27:24,391 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@2b5e08f5 for operation add-deployer-chains at address [] failed -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

By increasing timeout using command

```sh
$ bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=3600
```

It failed with error below

```
17:26:32,383 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Initializing database schema. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
17:31:25,854 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:f in state  RUN
17:31:25,870 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:f
17:31:27,355 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:12 in state  RUN
17:31:27,356 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:12
17:31:31,222 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:15 in state  RUN
17:31:31,225 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:15 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
17:31:31,250 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:15 completed with multiple threads - thread ServerService Thread Pool -- 68 was in progress with java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180)
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:533)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:703)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:642)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:941)
com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:887)
com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1073)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:724)
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.execute(WrappedStatement.java:198)
liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.updateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:182)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:102)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:81)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$2.run(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:341)
org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:334)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:306)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:182)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$$Lambda$802/938288417.run(Unknown Source)
org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:682)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:133)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:81)
org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:59)
org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:204)
org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:51)
org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:33)
org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:204)
org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.realmLocalStorage(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:157)
org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealmDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:148)
org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getMigrationModel(RealmCacheSession.java:141)
org.keycloak.migration.MigrationModelManager.migrate(MigrationModelManager.java:97)
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateModel(KeycloakApplication.java:244)
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.migrateAndBootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:185)
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:147)
org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$$Lambda$778/1366630785.run(Unknown Source)
org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:125)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2805)
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:369)
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:281)
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:92)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$734/2095679667.call(Unknown Source)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$735/1593765930.call(Unknown Source)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$735/1593765930.call(Unknown Source)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$735/1593765930.call(Unknown Source)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$735/1593765930.call(Unknown Source)
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

17:31:31,252 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:15 aborting with 1 threads active!
17:31:31,252 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:15
17:31:31,514 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:15
17:31:31,516 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:12
17:31:31,517 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffff7f000101:84ae906:5ee761e5:f
17:31:31,518 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update database
17:31:31,520 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
17:31:32,024 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped sessions cache from keycloak container
17:31:32,038 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment keycloak-server.war (runtime-name: keycloak-server.war) in 490ms
17:31:32,068 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd.java:86)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:527)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:448)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:401)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17:31:32,081 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
17:31:32,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 10.0.1 (WildFly Core 11.1.1.Final) stopped in 584ms
```

I am looking for solution like:

1. If I could get initial DDL & DML of Keycloak
2. If Keycloak could continue from where it failed
3. If timeout could be increased. In this case, I tried below command but it not work

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password -e DB_VENDOR=mysql -e DB_DATABASE=keycloak -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=keycloak -e DB_ADDR=mysql -e ROOT_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG -e JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=900" -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG --link=mysql jboss/keycloak
```

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue today, after my Keycloak instance suddenly stopped working.

I took a look at my underlying PostgreSQL database and retrieved the locks.
And what I saw, was that a Liquibase lock was not released.

So I used this commmand to search for open activities inside the PostgreSQL DB:

```
SELECT pid, state, username, query, query_start
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pid in (
  select pid from pg_locks l
  join pg_class t on l.relation = t.oid
  where t.relkind = 'r'
);
```

which returned the following:

```
pid | state  | usename  |                                query                                 |          query_start
-----+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------
  32 | active | keycloak | SELECT ID FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1000 FOR UPDATE | 2020-10-11 14:21:07.396058+00
 354 | active | keycloak | SELECT ID FROM public.databasechangeloglock WHERE ID=1000 FOR UPDATE | 2020-10-11 19:42:06.636659+00
```

Those database locks come from Liquibase which is used by Keycloak to upgrade your data structure/definition. Those locks were not released while upgrading the schema.

After dropping the table, the service now works again.

```
DROP TABLE databasechangeloglock;
```

In my case neither increasing the blocking timeout nor adding a default timeout to the transaction manager worked.

```
<coordinator-environment default-timeout="600" .../> # did not work
...
JAVA_TOOLS_OPTS: "-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=3600" # did not work
```

Comment: thanks  after days of going crazy about this, you really helped me with this insight

Comment: Thanks. Your answer provided the root cause and the fix for our issue with keycloak container.

Comment: Wow... that was my issue as well. After hours on it I was just on getting mad, so many thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

Seems that your keycloak tried to update schema during startup and it took too much time, so wildfly broke Keycloak deployment by timeout. Try to add following property to wildfly:

```
${KEYCLOAK_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=3600
```

Answer (score 3):

If you running keycloak as docker container then try using the following env variable

```
JAVA_TOOLS_OPTS: "-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=3600"
```

**Note:** This will be displayed in the keycloak container logs. (This can be helpful to confirm whether keycloak picks up the env variable or not)

Let me know if this works and if you need anything.

Comment: If that doesn't work try disabling ipv6 on your system and restart keycloak. Generally, keycloak is taking more time to boot up for the first time. Keep that in mind.  

This may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout` seems wildfly's deployment timeout.

In the above error case (ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker) you can adjust the transaction timeout. It can be set in the `standalone-ha.xml` file. For examples, to set it to 600 seconds:

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:5.0">
    <coordinator-environment default-timeout="600"/>
    ...
  </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1):

For docker deployments, the environment variable to set is `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND`

Example:

`JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=7200"`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.
All solutions regarding the modification of timeout or system resources are just workarounds and does not always work.

Initially, I thought to a network problem. It was not. It was because of the database which became "locked". I did not tried the previous solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64308446/7529228, but I think it can work.

I did an "hardest" solution :

- I dumped the Postgres database (`docker exec -it f84 pg_dump -c -U keycloak keycloak --no-owner > db-dump.sql` where `f84` is the ID of the container)
- I removed the Keycloak instance (Volume, network, ... everything)
- I deployed a new Keycloak instance.
- I restored my database (`cat db-dump.sql | docker exec -i keycloak_postgres.1.kyu24eqvnwaahg1obmy5omtfh psql -U keycloak keycloak` - Adapt with your own container name)
- I restarted the keycloak instance, then problem solved.

Thanks to https://pvelati.dev/2021/03/dump-and-restore-postgres-db-with-docker/ for the database dump/restoration procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you choose the right MySQL version.

Use **MySQL 5.7** instead of MySQL 8.0.32 for Keycloak versions between 4.0.0 and 16.1.1. Or migrate to a newer Keycloak version.

Example of `docker-compose.yml` with Keycloak 16.1.0 using MySQL 5.7 (you can change the version; I also tested it with Keycloak 10).

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  mysql_data:
      driver: local

services:
  mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.0
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
        DB_ADDR: mysql
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
        # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the MySQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
        #JDBC_PARAMS: "connectTimeout=30000"
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - mysql
```

Run the following `docker-compose.yml` example to reproduce the error. The error example is using Keycloak 16.1.0 with MySQL 8.0.32, instead of MySQL 5.7.

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  mysql_data:
      driver: local

services:
  mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0.32
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.0
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
        DB_ADDR: mysql
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
        # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the MySQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
        #JDBC_PARAMS: "connectTimeout=30000"
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - mysql
```

And the following error message will appear:

```bash
Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back.
```

My advice is to check which MySQL version is compatible with your Keycloak.

Source:

- https://www.keycloak.org/docs/16.1/server_installation/index.html#mysql-database
- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/ef2c7027be5fb9a65c34e3511dc45c950831634e/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-mysql.yml